# setting up and maintaining summary collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

this [post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/retail-reference-architecture-part-1-building-flexible-searchable-low-latency-product) from official mongodb blog advises to set up a summary collection as a part of a retail DB model.

I'm wondering about the ideal way of setting up and maintaining such a collection.

Is this supposed to be done through some kind of a cronjob?

Is there some convenient mongodb feature allowing to do this painlessly?